# Soft Question: Algorithms: Will We (One Day) No Longer Need to Study Algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, math-history

I'm just now getting into the study of algorithms and it seems like as computers get faster and faster the need to study algorithms may begin to diminish.

How likely is it that in 50 years there won't be much of a demand for the analysis of algorithms (other than for historical purposes, for example).

***Edited to include:***

*The reason that I ask is that I'm interested in studying algorithms so much that I could see myself moving into a graduate level of research. However, if the field isn't even going to be around in 50 years, I'm going to study the basics and move onto something else...*

Comment: Computers will get faster and faster only when better and better algorithms are developed.

Comment: You won't get an excuse to skip class with that argument.  Even more, it makes you seem like you do need to take that in class. Specially, since over the years the speed of computing has increased rather linearly, while many basic/important problems can only be solved exponentially and we need them for huge sizes of the input.

Comment: Since the adventure of computers novel algorithms are  the "theorems" with most impact in applied mathematics.

Comment: One of Trefethen's maxims: *The fundamental law of computer science: As machines become more powerful, the efficiency of algorithms grows more important, not less.*

Comment: I like that Maxim. Can you extrapolate a bit on how some people might think that quantum computing would negate the analysis of algorithms while others, such as Trefethen, take an opposite approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euclidean geometry has existed for a long time and we certainly don't only study it for historical purposes.

Usually what happens with a field of mathematics is that it gets incorporated into something bigger and more complex when we attain total mastery of it. For example, from Euclidean geometry we've gotten a lot of tools useful in number theory, topology, and other areas.

With algorithm analysis there's quite a similar situation. In fact, euclid himself came up with an algorithm for calculating GCD's. In some sense, then, algorithms have been studied as long as geometry. The field's not going anywhere.

The last thing I'd like to say is that you should treat algorithms as a tool separate from, but useful in computer science. They've been around since before we had computers and they're still useful outside of computer science.